# Draw squares between two points

Tags: java

I'm working on some exercises and I've been stuck on this for some hours now (quite new to Java).
Anyhow, this is what I'm supposed to do:
When I run the program I will have a square in the middle of the screen and when I then click somewhere within that screen another square will be drawn at the place where I clicked and in-between these two points there are supposed to be 10 squares. So wherever I click there should always be 10 squares drawn between.

However, I can't make it to function properly.

This is what I've managed to do so far:

```
import se.lth.cs.ptdc.window.SimpleWindow;  
import se.lth.cs.ptdc.square.Square;


public class PrintSquares2 {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleWindow w = new SimpleWindow(600, 600, "PrintSquares2");
    int posX = 300;
    int posY = 300;
    int loop = 0;
    System.out.println("Skriv rotation");
    Square sq1 = new Square(posX,posY,200);
    sq1.draw(w);


            w.waitForMouseClick();
            int destX = w.getMouseX();
            int destY = w.getMouseY();
            System.out.println("Dest X: " + destX + " Dest Y: " + destY);
            System.out.println("Pos X: " + posX + " Pos Y: " + posY);
            SimpleWindow.delay(10);
            //sq1.erase(w);
            int jumpX = (destX - posX) / 10;
            int jumpY = (destY - posY) / 10;
            System.out.println(jumpX);


                while (posX < destX)
                {       
                    posX = posX+10;
                    SimpleWindow.delay(100);
                    loop++;
                    System.out.println("Loop: " + loop);
                    System.out.println("Dest X: " + destX + " Dest Y: " + destY);
                    System.out.println("Pos X: " + posX + " Pos Y: " + posY);       
                    Square sq2 = new Square(posX,posY,200);         
                    sq2.draw(w);                        
                }

                while (posX > destX)
                {
                    posX = posX-10;
                    SimpleWindow.delay(100);
                    loop++;
                    System.out.println("Loop: " + loop);
                    System.out.println("Dest X: " + destX + " Dest Y: " + destY);
                    System.out.println("Pos X: " + posX + " Pos Y: " + posY);
                    sq1.draw(w);
                    Square sq2 = new Square(posX,posY,200);         
                    sq2.draw(w);
                }

                while (posY < destY)
                {       
                    posY = posY+10;
                    SimpleWindow.delay(100);
                    loop++;
                    System.out.println("Loop: " + loop);
                    System.out.println("Dest X: " + destX + " Dest Y: " + destY);
                    System.out.println("Pos X: " + posX + " Pos Y: " + posY);
                    sq1.draw(w);
                    Square sq2 = new Square(posX,posY,200);         
                    sq2.draw(w);
                }

                while (posY > destY)
                {
                    posY = posY-10;
                    SimpleWindow.delay(100);
                    loop++;
                    System.out.println("Loop: " + loop);
                    System.out.println("Dest X: " + destX + " Dest Y: " + destY);
                    System.out.println("Pos X: " + posX + " Pos Y: " + posY);
                    sq1.draw(w);
                    Square sq2 = new Square(posX,posY,200);         
                    sq2.draw(w);
                }


            SimpleWindow.delay(10);
            sq1.draw(w);

            //SimpleWindow.clear(w);


    }
```

}

I'm pretty sure that I overcomplicated everything since this should be pretty basic.

The end result is supposed to look like this:
[End result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxUM2.png)

Comment: And what is the current result you get?

Comment: Do you get an Exception somewhere?

Comment: This is how it looks at the moment. It first moves on the x-axis and then on the y-axis. http://i.imgur.com/3D9af.png

Comment: It appears that each new square is displaced both horizontally AND vertically while each square in your image is either moving horizontally OR vertically but never both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way I'd have solved it:

I didn't quite understand the documentation on `se.lth.cs.ptdc.square.Square` but I'll assume it draws a square given the coordinates of its top-left corner and a side size.

So you have the coodinates of your first square's left-top corner and the coordinates of the last square's center. Having that it's not difficult to get the coords of the last square's top-left corner:
`lastX = centerX - side/2`
`lastY = centerY - side/2`

After you have that you find the difference between the starting and ending points:
`diffX = posX - lastX`
`diffY = posY - lastY`

and after that just draw 9 more squares:

```
for (int i=1; i<10; i++){
    squareX = posX + (diffX/10)*i;
    squareY = posY + (diffY/10)*i;
    Square square = new Square(squareX,squareY,200);         
    square.draw(w);
}
```

Actually you did the first part right, just messed up with those unnecessary checks. Hope it helps.

--
Regards, svz.

Answer (score 1):

Update both X and Y at the SAME time :

```
    int jumpX = (destX - posX) / 10;
    int jumpY = (destY - posY) / 10;
    if (posX > destX) {
        int temp = destX;
        destX = posX;
        posX = temp;
    }

    while (posX <= destX)
    {       
            SimpleWindow.delay(100);
            loop++;
            System.out.println("Loop: " + loop);
            System.out.println("Dest X: " + destX + " Dest Y: " + destY);
            System.out.println("Pos X: " + posX + " Pos Y: " + posY);       
            Square sq2 = new Square(posX,posY,200);         
            sq2.draw(w);                        
            posX = posX+jumpX;
            posY = posY+jumpY;
    }    

    SimpleWindow.delay(10);
    sq1.draw(w);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, had to get going for my math lecture and then take the train home. I tried the above code and made some slight modifications to it but I have a small issue with it. Whenever I click on the right side of the original square the animation gets offset but it still loops the correct number of times. 
See this picture: http://imgur.com/a/T0ibA 

The only thing I changed in the code was :
    if (posX < destX){
and
    while (posX >= destX && posY >= destY) {

Comment: Otherwise if I use the code you provided it will get offset + loop to infinity when clicked on one side.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you move in two directions at once (on a diagonal).

```
static final int Steps = 10;

private void test() {
  int x1 = 100;
  int y1 = 100;
  int x2 = 300;
  int y2 = 500;

  double dx = (double)(x2 - x1) / (double) Steps;
  double dy = (double)(y2 - y1) / (double) Steps;

  double x = x1;
  double y = x2;
  for ( int i = 0; i < Steps; i++) {
    // Simulate the drawing of the square.
    System.out.println("("+x+","+y+")");
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
  }
}
```